# Use of polymer paper-fab and documentation

Tags: button, element, polymer

I am trying to use polymer project in a website but I am stuck and cannot find help on the documentation.

How do I use the click of a paper-fab element? I have seen on another stackoverflow post the use of the property on-tap= . I have seen the docs and the code and could not find any place that says this property exists.

Should I add a event handler? Is this how polymer works?

My code:

```
 <!-- `keepCondensedHeader` makes the condensed header to not scroll away -->
    <core-scroll-header-panel condenses keepCondensedHeader condensedHeaderHeight="80">

        <core-toolbar>

            <div flex></div>
            <core-icon-button icon="thumb-up"></core-icon-button>
            <paper-fab icon="account-circle" ></paper-fab>

            <div class="bottom indent bottom-text" self-end>
                <div>ME AVISE</div>
                <div class="subtitle">Fique informado e economize</div>
            </div>

        </core-toolbar>

        <div class="content">

            <lorem-ipsum paragraphs="100"></lorem-ipsum>

        </div>

    </core-scroll-header-panel>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your posted code is inside another Polymer element you can add `on-tap={{yourHandlerMethod}}` to the `paper-fab` element. If you're outside Polymer, then yes, you can just `el.addEventListener('tap', function() { ... })`.

See [here](https://github.com/Polymer/PointerGestures) for the available events.

Comment: How about onclick in html? Can you use that?

Comment: Yes, you can use `onclick`.

Comment: and what about if I want to set the fill value in css core-icon svg?

Comment: Add `.a-class-on-your-button::shadow core-icon { fill: red; }` to your element styles (replace ".a-class-on-your-button" with whatever you need to select the `core-icon-button`, of course).